# Stackoverflow question migration

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

Growing number of posts on SO are related to installation of IDEs, libraries and programming tools on Ubuntu. Some of them might be a fit for Serverfault but they are usually far too easy to be valuable for professional sysadmins Q&A site.

A lot of them would fit nicely into Ask Ubuntu as they are usually questions about installing Oracle Java or finding a PPA with a newer version of some application.

On Serverfault meta they discuss leaving the spot on flagging for migration of a question (off-topic -> belongs on {sitename}). How about taking their (Serverfault's) place in this migration dialog?

I do not propose to have user-started migration, only to add Ask Ubuntu to the list in flagging "off-topic->belongs on " in SO flag dialog. Currently Ubuntu-related questions are probably getting flagged as "belongs on Serverfault" which is clearly wrong and flags aren't helpful in that way. This might be also frustrating for Serverfault folks having to deal with migrated but misplaced questions in their community.

Comment: I believe this should rather be said on meta.SO because it has more to do with SO than our side.

Comment: I already asked them about it and they directed me here and to Serverfault meta. I posted this question on all of those metas.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155411/ask-ubuntu-as-off-topic-migration-slot/155414#155414

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [stackoverflow faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) it states

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>   ... but if your question generally covers ...
>
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

This means that IDEs, libraries and programming tools etc. available on Ubuntu (and other platforms) are on topic for Stack Overflow, so there is no need to have them migrated away.

Looking at the last 300 inbound migrations to serverfault (from all sites) only 11 of them had an [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) tag of some description. We closed 5 of them as NARQ and the rest appear to have a home on SF although the jury is still out on some of them.

Comment: Now if only the SO community would read the FAQ and realize there was no need to migrate those questions away...

Comment: @MichaelHampton: How to educate the great unwashed - there's a challenge. Cattle prods, pointy sticks and loss of rep for rejected migrations ...

Comment: Please, please, please. Nobody is prodding anyone, and I don't feel SE should dock rep for a rejected migration.